# Rails using ActionView::Helper methods outside of view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a helper which I'd like to use for text manipulation

```
module ApplicationHelper

  module TextHelper

    extend ActionView::Helpers

  end
end
```

However when I run `ApplicationHelper::TextHelper.simple_format "foo"` in Rails console I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `white_list_sanitizer' for Module:Class
```

Is there anything else I need included?

I have already looked at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13837 but it didn't work.

Using Rails 4, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Why are you using ``extend`` and not ``include``?

Comment: `include` produces `NoMethodError: undefined method 'simple_format' for ApplicationHelper::TextHelper:Module`

Comment: `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`. That's where `simple_format` comes from!

Comment: I've tried the example from here http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=256. If this is what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in the console, you should be able to just do `helper.simple_format('hi')`. The `helper` method is available in console as a way to call some helper methods.

When using a custom helper:

```
# app/helpers/custom_helper.rb
module CustomHelper
  def custom_method(x)
    puts "Custom method #{x}"
  end
end

# from the console
helper.custom_method('hi')

# from the controller
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    view_context.custom_method('hi')
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using the console for testing, my end goal is to have other data editing helpers use it.

Comment: So you want to create your own custom helper, and use your own custom methods, but be able to see how they work in the console?

Comment: Yup. I get the same error if run it from a controller.

Comment: That did work, but what if I want to call `view_context.custom_method('hi')` from another Helper initiated from a Controller. This means I have to pass view_context all the way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You don't have to pass the view_context. All helpers are included automatically. If one helper calls a method from another helper, then you call it in the controller, they will both run.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use helpers with [`ActionController::Base.helpers`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html#method-i-helpers) or (and) with [`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet.html)

For example

```rb
helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers
url_helpers = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

helpers.link_to "Root_path", url_helpers.root_path
# => "<a href=\"/\">Root_path</a>"
```